# fields_for rails with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selection, form-for, fields-for

I have a Rails application, in it I has an Entity model which has a Type and a Category models, I’m trying to use fields_for but I already have existing data, I don't need to create a new one, so my question is, it's possible, is there another helper method with this functionality?, or  I should keep my way of bring them via Ajax and display it in the page dynamically and then sends users selections via json?

Comment: You won't need ajax there.  Could you please post some code that you've tried so that we can move forward with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think reading Rails Guides may help you (not only with this problem)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Also, check out Ryan Bates
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1